# Don't render html.tpl.php for a specific path

Tags: theming

Is it possible to load page content without rendering html.tpl.php? I mean on default Drupal has the follwoing:

Html.tpl.php --> Page.tpl.php -->...(etc.)

my goal is to remove Html.tpl.php for a custom path (site://ajax-unesco)

so:

page--ajax-unesco.tpl.php --> ... (etc.)

Comment: is ajax-unesco content type ?

Comment: keying in on the ajax portion of your path, if you are wanting Drupal to just output the $content of a page instead of all the various wrappings, in that menu callback, PRINT what you want instead of RETURNing it.

Comment: It`s a view, i wanna get its contents by ajax call without additional data (like html.tpl contents).

Comment: @Jimajamma i didn't get it, currently i have a view with page display and a template file called "page--ajax-unesco.tpl.php (my view name) i'm rendering with the following code:
<?php  print render($page['content']); ?>

Comment: have you tried creating html--ajax-unesco.tpl.php in templates file ? you can create and keep it blank and test.

Comment: @sandeshyadav i tested it right now, but no results.

Comment: did you clear the cache ? And sorry dont put it blank.    put <?php print $page_top; ?>
<?php print $page; ?>
<?php print $page_bottom; ?>
in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu
 */
function MY_MODULE_menu(){
  $items = array();
  $items['clean/view'] = array(
    'page callback'    => 'MY_MODULE_clean_view',
    'page arguments'   => array(2, 3),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type'             => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Menu callback for clean/view
 * Output view without wrapper page markup
 */
function MY_MODULE_clean_view($name, $display = 'default'){
  // Note views_embed_view performs views access check
  print views_embed_view($name, $display);
  drupal_exit();
}
```

You can then use the dynamic path `/clean/view/view_name/display_id` to render the View without the wrapper markup.